# Install Filebeat locally or in the VM?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I recently started learning ELK and I succeed to parse my XML files locally. But now I would like to have access to my server to get access to all of my XML files (upgrade every 30 seconds)
I have the ip-address of my server and my question is: should I install Filebeat locally and configure my filebeat.yml to get access to the server or I should install the Filebeat in the server and then indicate my locally address?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. See ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Filebeat is a shipper, which collects, aggregate and forward logs to your desired output (logstash, elasticsearch etc).

It works as an agent, so you need to install it in every node from which you want to collect logs from. For instance, if you want to collect logs from your local machine then install filebeat there, if you want to collect from logstash server itself, then install filebeat there. If you want to collect log from both, then filebeat needs to be installed in  both machines. and use `logstash` as an output,
have a look at [this illustration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-overview.html),

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sufiyan for your response, but if I can't install it in the server where I have all my data, I couldn't install it locally and configure the input of the filebeat to have access to the server? for example using in the input the ip-address of the server ?

Comment: this is not practical ideally, please have a look https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/how-filebeat-works.html

Answer (score -1):

But when I tried to install `filebeat` on my server using

> curl -L -O elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-6.3.1-amd64.deb

I get this message:

> Could not resolve host: www.elastic.co; Name or service not known

The OS version of the server is : Linux version 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64